# How to Expand OutlookFormRegion in C#?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-form-region

I am facing am issue in Outlook VSTO addIn where OutlookFormRegion is used in Adjoining FormRegionType. So is there a way to change its state i.e. expand (if region is collapsed) via C#?

I could not find a location where this state persists? In my opinion, we can change this by accessing this?

Also share your thoughts if we can disable this expand/collapse option?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using Outlook Task Pane instead of a form region: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry,  any idea about how to use Outlook Task Pane in similar to FormRegion particular in Adjoining mode?

Comment: You can add your task pane at the bottom of an inspector.